# How to trigger a function when a checkbox is selected or deselected in react ag-grid

Tags: reactjs, ag-grid

guys basically I'm trying to trigger a function when any of the checkbox is selected or deselected, for this I'm using a cellRenderer: "agCheckboxCellRenderer", onSelectionChanged is not useful in this case because i need to use the selected rows for other porpuses, so that's why i want to trigger the function exclusively using the checkbox, is there a way i can do this? or is there a way that after selecting the checkbox the cell where the checkbox is nested get selected and triggers the function that i need?, because when i click on the checkbox the cell doesn't get selected

this is basically de definition of my ag-grid table

```
const hashValueGetter = (params) => {
      return params.node ? params.node.rowIndex + 1 : null;
    };

    const [colDefs, setColDefs] = useState([]);

    const defaultLabelColumns = [
      {
        headerName: "Hide",
        field: "checked",
        cellRenderer: "agCheckboxCellRenderer",
        cellRendererParams: {
          disabled: false,
        },
        maxWidth: 70,
      },
      {
        field: "make",
        headerName: "Case #",
        maxWidth: 80,
        valueGetter: hashValueGetter,
      },
      { field: "name", headerName: "Line Name", width: 180 },
    ];

const defaultColDef = useMemo(() => {
      return {
        resizable: true,
        filter: false,
      };
    }, []);

    const onSelectionChanged: (params: any) => void = useCallback(
      (params: any) => {
        const selectedNodes: any = params.api.getSelectedNodes();
        console.log("selected nodes",selectedNodes);
      },
      [plotData],
    );
   <div
      className="ag-theme-balham"
      style={{ height: "100%", width: "99%", maxWidth: "99%" }}
    >
      <AgGridReact
        columnDefs={colDefs}
        defaultColDef={defaultColDef}
        rowData={plotData}
        rowHeight={30}
        pagination={true}
        paginationPageSize={4}
        rowSelection="multiple"
        domLayout="autoHeight"
        animateRows={true}
        onSelectionChanged={onSelectionChanged}
      />
    </div>
```

If i need to provide more specification please let me know guys

Answer (score 0):

I managed this by using onCellValueChanged and specifying the column where my checkboxes are, this way i can trigger a function when any of the checkboxes get selected or deselected

```
const onCellValueChanged = (event: any) => {
      if (event.colDef.field === "checked") {
        event.api.forEachNode((node) => {
          if (node.data.checked) {
            plotData[node.rowIndex].visible = false
          }
          else {
            plotData[node.rowIndex].visible = true
          }
          setPlotData([...plotData])
        });
      }
    };

        <div
          className="ag-theme-balham"
          style={{ height: "100%", width: "99%", maxWidth: "99%" }}
        >
          <AgGridReact
            columnDefs={colDefs}
            defaultColDef={defaultColDef}
            rowData={plotData}
            rowHeight={30}
            pagination={true}
            paginationPageSize={4}
            rowSelection="multiple"
            domLayout="autoHeight"
            animateRows={true}
            onSelectionChanged={onSelectionChanged}
            onCellValueChanged={onCellValueChanged}
          />
        </div>
```